# Cannot convert the "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientResult`1[System.IO.Stream]" to type "System.IO.Stream"

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, file

I am copying a file. I do not have it on the local machine. Method .CopyTo() and .Move() is out of question. Environment is SharePoint Online. 
The file is loaded correctly and I access its properties, e.g. `Write-Host $sFile.ServerRelativeUrl`. However when I try to pass `$FileStream` to `.ContentStream` I receive the error:

> Cannot convert the
>   "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientResult'1[System.IO.Stream]" value
>   of type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientResult'1[[System.IO.Stream,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,  Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]" to type "System.IO.Stream".

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]$sFile=[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]$litem.File # file is from SharePoint library item; cast is a desperate attempt
    $ctx.Load($sFile)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    $fci = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
    $fci.ContentStream=[System.IO.Stream]$sFile.OPenBinaryStream()
    $fci.Overwrite=$false
    $fci.Url=$urlEnd
    $dFile = $ll2.RootFolder.Files.Add($fci)  
    $dFile.Update()
    $ctx2.ExecuteQuery()
```

What I tried so far:

```
$sBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($sFile)
$fci.Content=$sBytes
```

> Exception calling "ReadAllBytes" with "1" argument(s): "Could not find
>   file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File'."

- FileStream

  ```
  $FileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream("https://tenant"+$sFile.ServerRelativeUrl,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
  ```

The given path's format is not supported.

**Question:**
How can I convert Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientResult[System.IO.Stream] to [System.IO.Stream]?

Answer (score 1):

Your code returns result in ClientResult format.

Use
 [System.IO.Stream($file.OPenBinaryStream().Value)

May it helps you.

Comment: No :(  At the .ExecutionQuery() I get    Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "parameters.Content, parameters.ContentStream
Parameter name: Specified value is not supported for the parameters.Content, parameters.ContentStream parameter."